# What is the role of the capacitors in this circuit?

Tags: circuit-analysis

What is the role of the 10uF capacitors in this circuit? I know that the 47uF capacitor acts as bypassing capacitor, but what about the 10uF ones.

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The 10 uF capacitors block DC.

- The circuit is a signal or AC amplifier.
- The input is oscillating about 0 V but the amplifier only has a positive supply so it can't swing negative.
- The base resistors bias (add a DC offset to) the transistor so that the output is near half-supply to give maximum output voltage swing. The amplifier output can then swing either side of this voltage in proportion to the input signal.
- The input capacitor (to the base) couples the AC signal in and prevents DC going back to the 4 kHz source. As the source voltage oscillates around 0 V the base voltage will oscillate around its DC bias point.
- The output capacitor blocks the DC component so that Vout swings above and below 0 V.

This is the configuration of many battery powered or single-rail audio amplifiers.

Comment: What about the capacitor in the base? Whys that used?

Answer (score 1):

These capacitors block out the DC voltage in the input signal (Vin) and the output signal (Vout).This happens because capacitors are frequency dependent, for the DC voltage they are open circuits and it does not affect Vin or Vout signal.

Answer (score 0):

Coupling capacitor is the searchterm you're looking for.

Comment: True, but a little explanation would be nice.

Comment: true, standing on the shoulders of searchengine experts and electronic experts but this was what I needed a few months ago while figuring out this exact same question.